# How do I choose between Stack Overflow, Programmers and Code Review?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

How does one decide which forum to post in?  I tried to see if the different sites had a "home" page with an intro of sorts that explains what NOT to post etc. but I haven't really gotten a clear idea.

So far, from what I understand, Code Review would be for questions around how to improve a piece of code. But I'm not sure what the difference is between Stack Overflow and Programmers.

I just want to double check so that I don't loose points for posting on the wrong site!